# Where can I find a high quality copy of Turing's On Computable Numbers?

Tags: turing-machines, reference-request, history

Currently, I'm reading a [photocopied version](http://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs129/caltech_restricted/Turing_1936_IBID.pdf) of Turing's famous article *On Computable Numbers, With an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem*.

This is the best photocopy of his paper that I can find; most other copies are of pretty low quality to the point that I can't distinguish between different characters. The e in the *final m-config* column on page 233 for example, looks exactly like a c on many copies (not the one I'm using though). I also have trouble distinguishing between the german capitol letters C and E later in his paper on page 238 and such. Is there any place where I can find a well copied version of the paper? Perhaps a book would have a nice copy.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very [high resolution scan in the Turing Digital Archive](http://www.turingarchive.org/browse.php/B/12), however it's presented via a flash player plugin which makes reading mildy awkward and doesn't seem to allow printing.

There are a handful of marginally nicer PDF copies than that Caltech one you link available online [[1]](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf)[[2]](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-42/1/230.full.pdf+html), however they all seem to have been drawn from the same photocopy at some point.

Comment: Blocking Javascript will get you access to the JPG files on turingarchive.org. That said, LaTeXing famous old articles would be a great community project.

Comment: Reference [2] above of PLMS at Oxford journals is the "official" source, it is the digital archive of the official journal where Computable Numbers was published. There is a "reprint" (with slightly different formatting) at Annual Review in Automatic Programming Volume 1, 1960, Pages 230–264, [doi:10.1016/0066-4138(60)90045-8](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0066-4138(60)90045-8) which has slightly "fatter" font and might be better readable. Not open access though.

Comment: @HendrikJan I can't even access this with my university license. Wow.

Comment: @Raphael This would seem like a great job for specialist OCR software and a lot of expertise.

Comment: @Lembik OCR on mathematics? That way only madness lies, methinks.

Comment: @Raphael Or... glory :) Maybe computer assistance would be more appropriate than full automation. http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/benb.ps is an effort I see and it has a number of citations to it.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Hawking's collection [God Created the Integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Created_the_Integers) has that paper included, as well as a lot of other pivotal math papers.

EDIT: Here's a preview on [Google Books](http://books.google.nl/books?id=j0dkJQwORvYC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA1293#v=onepage&q&f=false).